# n level Expandable Listview

Tags: android

How to display n- level of expandable list view android, I am getting only examples for 3-Levels expandable.

Referring this :[link](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84)

Please guideline or share me suitable example for Multi-level expandable display in android.

Thanks,

Comment: See is the link for My project where N-level Tree list view can be achieved.https://github.com/Jaldips/Android-MultilevelTreeListView

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/nested-expandable-recyclerview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [example](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84).

```
   public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,

                   boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

             CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(Vincent_ThreeelevellistActivity.this);

             SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());

             SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);

             return SecondLevelexplv;

      }
```

Here the `getChildView` method creates a new adapter by `CustExpListview`  Class and sets is as an Adapter.
The same way you can create a new  `BaseExpandableListAdapter` Class and set it in `CustExpListview` Class `getChildView` method.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but confirm me one thing how to control click of multi-level parents and child in expandable view.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: Yup! This link is not working. Can you show other link or complete example?

Comment: did not work for me since the Custom ExpandableListView is taking a static height and width in onMeasure. it will only work if the expandable contains a simple textview and is 3 lists. more than 3 wont appear...