# Nth Level Expandable ListView

Tags: android

I am trying to implement nth level `Expandable ListView` as android only supports 2-level Expandable List. After Googling for an hour found some solutions but most of them are till 3-level and some with incomplete documentation. I want something which can expend according to data to nth level hierarchy.

If any one has some idea please share.

Thanks

Comment: can you post the code that you have tried so far

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I Followed this link to make two level list successfully. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010366/n-level-expandable-listview?rq=1

Comment: @PhanVănLinh Thank You. Will let you know the result for the same.

Comment: check this link is what you want http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84 @Umesh Chauhan

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I was able to implement nth level tree in my navigation drawer. Thanks